# PostBack Not Happening For A Radio Button

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I check rbEmployee, the postback occurs, but it doesnt for rbBatch. Why is it so.

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbBatch" runat="server" Text="Batch" GroupName="OB"
CausesValidation="false" AutoPostBack="true" 
OnCheckedChanged="rbBatch_CheckedChanged"/>

<asp:RadioButton ID="rbEmployee" runat="server" Text="Employee" GroupName="OB"
CausesValidation="false" AutoPostBack="true" 
OnCheckedChanged="rbEmployee_CheckedChanged"/>

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
 <Triggers>
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rbBatch" EventName="CheckedChanged"/>
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rbEmployee" EventName="CheckedChanged"/>
 </Triggers>
 <ContentTemplate>
   <asp:GridView ID="gvBatch" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
   <asp:GridView ID="gvMain" runat="server" visible="false"></asp:GridView>
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**C#:**

```
protected void rbBatch_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(rbBatch.Checked)
   {
     gvBatch.visible=true;
     gvMain.visible=false;
   }
}

protected void rbEmployee_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(rbEmployee.Checked)
   {
     gvBatch.visible=false;
     gvMain.visible=true;
   }
}
```

Comment: How are you checking for the `PostBack` event

Comment: Break point in code behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsyncPostBack Trigger only works in the UpdatePanel so Move the RadioButtons to the UpdatePanel and Try Again.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Any reason, why it was working for only one of the buttons before?

Comment: I think he should also implement my solution (with your one)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CausesValidation="true"?

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you select A, B's event doesn't fire (unless was recently selected).

A better solution is as follows:

```
protected void rbBatch_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  handle();
}

protected void rbEmployee_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  handle();
}

private void handle()
{
   if(rbBatch.Checked)
   {
     gvBatch.visible=true;
     gvMain.visible=false;
   }
   else if(rbEmployee.Checked)
   {
     gvBatch.visible=false;
     gvMain.visible=true;
   }
}
```